# first row and last row fields value from where data changed

Tags: oracle, plsql, greatest-n-per-group

Assume I have a table like this:

[image]

I'm trying the have a output like following picture

[image]

How best to achieve this?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT job_title, 
       charge_center,
       MIN(id) start_id,
       MAX(id) end_id
FROM source_table
GROUP BY job_title, charge_center;
```

---

If there exists 2 separate blocks with the same `(job_title, charge_center)` pair values the query will give wrong result.